# Euclidean distance

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I would like to check whether the following inequality is valid for all $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\sqrt{(p_1-q_1)^2 + \cdots + (p_n-q_n)^2} 
\leq \sqrt{(p_1-q_1)^2} + \cdots + \sqrt{(p_n-q_n)^2} $$

I was checking it by taking random numbers and I found it still true. But how can  I prove it generally? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $a_i=|p_i-q_i|$, you are trying to check whether $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2$$ Given $a_i\ge0$ for all $i=1\cdots,n$, this inequality is indeed true as
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=\sum_{\substack{i, j=1\\i\ne j}}^na_ia_j\ge0$$